# Foreseen way to access a component from another component in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Would it be a bad practice to access an application component from another component? If yes: why? If no: What would be the best practice to do that? I didn't find any good advice for this question in the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any component from anywhere in you application via `Yii::$app->componentName`.

But i don't think that this is a good practice to do it directly that way.

At least, to keep your component isolated, you should keep in mind that `componentName` is a subject op parent application configuration. 
So as minimum you should include the name of referenced component into dependent component configuration.

In your `components/MyComponent.php`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
  public $referencedComponentName = 'defaultName';
  ...
}
```

In `config/web.php`:

```
...
components => [
  'myComponent' => [
    ...
    'referencedComponentName' => 'otherComponent'
  ]
]
```

So you can call other comonent in your component code like this:

```
use yii;
...
class MyComponent extends Component
{
  ...
  public function getReferencedComponent()
  {
    return \Yii::$app->get($this->referencedComponentName);
  }
```

**But this way also not very good.** According to [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) Depenency inversion principle the better way will be to define some abstraction for 
referenced component (interface for exampe), which will be implemented in parent application config. But here i cant't provide valuable example 
because i don't know your particular task and application structure.

Comment: Thanks [@maxim-korshunov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6479466) for the elaborate answer. I suppose you are right in every respect.